# Purpose of divide-by-2 (or CLK/2) on a video pixel clock generator ICs

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal-processing, video, rgb, asic

I've been looking into some video clock generator chips and almost all of them have a divide-by-2 or CLK/2 output pin (in addition to the normal CLK out).  What would be the purpose or application for such a pin?  I would think a multiplier would be more handy, especially for up-scaling video designs.

**Sample from Datasheet:**
[image]

[image]

**Another chip sample:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a couple of reasons.

From the [MC44145 datasheet:](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=644276&part-number=MC44145)

[image]

First off is to adjust the clock to a better range for the VCO that drives the pixel clock PLL so that the VCO control voltage stays within a usable range.

The other reason is to provide a square wave with a 50% duty cycle for the pixel genetator.